# How to activate features of EPIC Perl plugin for Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, perl, eclipse-plugin, epic

I just downloaded the EPIC Perl plugin for Eclipse and then opened a Perl script (.pl) contained within an existing C++ project.  The editor does not have syntax highlighting or any of the other promised features of EPIC.  The only thing that has changed is that the script has a camel icon in the Project Explorer.

I open a different .pl file in a different directory within the same project and it works (syntax highlighting).

How do I activate the features of EPIC for the first file?

I'm using Eclipse Kepler on Windows 7.

(the only thing I can think of is that the first file was open in Eclipse before I installed the plugin, the second file was not.  But closing/reopening the file and/or Eclipse does not fix the problem)

Comment: I've encountered this. Oh so long ago. You gotta right-click on the *file*. But I can't remember what you have to choose after. Open As? Open With? Or maybe it had "view", "type" or "nature" in the name? Once you do it, Eclipse will remember. In fact, that's the problem. Eclipse is remembering which editor you used to open the file the last time you opened it, and it wasn't EPIC's (since you didn't have it yet).

Comment: That was it!  You da man :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right-click on the the file in the Navigator, choose "Open With" and then "Epic Perl Editor".